# Multiple plots sharing a single vertical axis

Tags: plotting, graphics, grid-layouts, alignment

I am trying to align a series of plots horizontally. They all share a vertical axis, but I only want to show the axis once on the leftmost plot. However, adding the vertical axis on one of the plots messes up the aspect ratio/scaling. For example, I can set it up this way

```
test = Reverse@Table[Table[i, {i, -1, 1, j}], {j, 0.1, 0.5, 0.1}];
len1 = Length@test[[All, 1]];
rule = {False, False};
GraphicsGrid[
 Partition[
  Table[
   Plot[test[[i]], {x, 0, .1}, ColorFunction -> "FallColors", 
    AspectRatio -> 3, Axes -> rule, 
    PlotLabel -> "N = " <> ToString[i]], {i, 1, len1}],
  len1],
 ImageSize -> Full]
```

The result looks like this:

[image: no axis]

However when I try to add the axis on the leftmost plot, by doing

```
test = Reverse@Table[Table[i, {i, -1, 1, j}], {j, 0.1, 0.5, 0.1}];
len1 = Length@test[[All, 1]];
GraphicsGrid[
 Partition[
  Table[If[i == 1, rule = {False, True}, rule = {False, False}];
   Plot[test[[i]], {x, 0, .1}, ColorFunction -> "FallColors", 
    AspectRatio -> 3, Axes -> rule, 
    PlotLabel -> "N = " <> ToString[i]], {i, 1, len1}],
  len1],
 ImageSize -> Full]
```

then the leftmost plot does gets compressed due to the fixed aspect ratio

[image: with axis]

any help appreciated, also I appreciate any suggestions for improving my plots. My plot looks like this:

[image]

Comment: maybe `GraphicsGrid[
 Partition[Table[If[i == 1, style = Automatic, style = Opacity[0]];
   Plot[test[[i]], {x, 0, .1}, ColorFunction -> "FallColors", 
    AspectRatio -> 3, Axes -> {False, True}, AxesStyle -> style, 
    PlotLabel -> "N = " <> ToString[i]], {i, 1, len1}], len1], 
 ImageSize -> Full]`?

Comment: This works but creates I don't like the extra white space between the plots

Comment: How about this? `Grid[Partition[
  Table[If[i == 1, style = Automatic, style = Opacity[0]]; 
   LogLinearPlot[test[[i]], {x, 0, .1}, ColorFunction -> "FallColors", 
    AspectRatio -> 3, Axes -> {False, True}, AxesStyle -> style, 
    PlotLabel -> "N = " <> ToString[i], ImageSize -> Medium], {i, 1, 
    len1}], len1], Spacings -> -0.5]`

Comment: It helps but the spacings are still much larger than shown in my figure above, and making it more negative does't seem to decrease it any further past -1

Comment: How did you generate your last figure? In my case -2 works. Note I am using `Grid`

Comment: `GraphicsGrid[
 Partition[Table[If[i == 1, style = Automatic, style = Opacity[0]];
   Plot[test[[i]], {x, 0, .1}, ColorFunction -> "FallColors", 
    AspectRatio -> 3, Axes -> {False, True}, AxesStyle -> style, 
    PlotLabel -> "N = " <> ToString[i], 
    ImagePadding -> {{Scaled[.05], 0}, {Scaled[.05], 0}}, 
    PlotRangePadding -> 0], {i, 1, len1}], len1], ImageSize -> Full, 
 Spacings -> 0]`?

Comment: Oh I see, okay it does work with `Grid`, although it doesn't display quite so nicely in the notebook but that't not a huge deal.

Comment: @kglr I'm not sure what you've done here, it's definitely close but still slightly more space than desired between each. Thank you though

Answer (score 2):

`LevelScheme` (or `SciDraw`) ....

After loading the package:

```
Quiet@Needs["LevelScheme`LevelScheme`"]

ofig = Figure[{
   Multipanel[{1, 5},
    XPlotRanges -> {0, .1},
    YPlotRanges -> {-1., 1.25},
    XFrameLabels -> None, BufferB -> 2.5,
    YFrameLabels -> None, BufferL -> 3,
    XFrameTicks -> None,
    XPanelSizes -> 1, XGapSizes -> .05,
    YPanelSizes -> 1],
   FigurePanel[{1, 1}, ShowPanelLetter -> False, Frame -> False],
   RawGraphics@
    Plot[test[[1]], {x, 0, .1}, ColorFunction -> "FallColors"],
   ScaledLabel[{.5, .95}, "N=1", FontFamily -> "Helvetica LT Std"],
   FigurePanel[{1, 2}, ShowPanelLetter -> False, Frame -> False],
   RawGraphics@
    Plot[test[[2]], {x, 0, .1}, ColorFunction -> "FallColors"],
   ScaledLabel[{.5, .95}, "N=2", FontFamily -> "Helvetica LT Std"],
   FigurePanel[{1, 3}, ShowPanelLetter -> False, Frame -> False],
   RawGraphics@
    Plot[test[[3]], {x, 0, .1}, ColorFunction -> "FallColors"],
   ScaledLabel[{.5, .95}, "N=3", FontFamily -> "Helvetica LT Std"],
   FigurePanel[{1, 4}, ShowPanelLetter -> False, Frame -> False],
   RawGraphics@
    Plot[test[[4]], {x, 0, .1}, ColorFunction -> "FallColors"],
   ScaledLabel[{.5, .95}, "N=4", FontFamily -> "Helvetica LT Std"],
   FigurePanel[{1, 5}, ShowPanelLetter -> False, Frame -> False],
   RawGraphics@
    Plot[test[[5]], {x, 0, .1}, ColorFunction -> "FallColors"],
   ScaledLabel[{.5, .95}, "N=5", FontFamily -> "Helvetica LT Std"]
   },
  ImageSize -> .5 72 {PAGELENGTH, PAGEWIDTH}
  ]
```

gets us

[image]

There are many options for customisation & efficiency.